# Closed form solution that minimizes $\sum_{i} (x^\top A_i x - b_i)^2$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, closed-form, least-squares

I'm trying to solve the following minimization problem:
$$
x = \arg\min_x f(x) = \arg\min_x \sum_i (x^\top A_i x - b_i)^2,\\[0.5em]
x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \quad b_i\in\mathbb{R}^{+},\\[0.5em]
\quad A_i\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\,\, A_i \text{ positive definite and symmetric}
$$

After some simulations, there seems to be several local minima, with an error $f(x)>0$. For instance, with $n=2$ and for a set of valid values of $A_i$ and $y_i$, we have 4 local minima:

[image]

On the other hand, I believe this problem is equivalent to finding $x$ that gives the least-squares error of the system of equations with constraints $x^\top A_i x = b_i$ (not sure if this is useful, though).

Can the structure that this problem be leveraged to reach a non-iterative solution to it?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe a closed form solution exists?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone no, I don't. I have reasons to believe that a local minima exists, however I don't know if it can be reached in closed form.

Comment: That's why numerical optimizers (optimization solvers) were created. Most real world optimization problems don't have closed form solutions.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I completely agree, thanks for the feedback. I am curious if it exists since it would be really great in my application (I would expect the closed form solution to be much faster to compute, something that is valuable in my problem).